# WCF service reference in Metro (Store) application won't work after update

Tags: wcf, windows-store-apps, service-reference

Here's the scenario: On the server there's WCF service with some simple methods and few classes in it. The client is  Metro (Store) app. Communication between the two worked just fine after service reference is added and updated when changes are made in service class. I could pass the data perfectly. Then, after adding some new methods and classes in Wcf service, and few updates of reference...it broke.

There was nothing but some comments in Reference.cs, but no code. Creating new reference didn't work, it will generate empty reference class again and again. Updating reference didn't work either.

When I move Metro pages to new empty solution, and generate reference, it works again, and after a while...when I add new bunch of methods and such, it breaks (it works for few updates,tho). I don't understand why would that happen in one solution, but work in a new one, and happen again after a while. I couldn't see what triggers this problem.

Anyone had the same problem? I couldn't find the answer that answers this problem specifically for Metro app.

p.s. Excuse my English and lack of terms to explain the problem...ask if you need to know more. :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the warning-list after you refreshed the service reference? I often found quite a few interesting infos in there on service-reference errors.